# Use $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}$ to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

> I want to evaluate the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}$ with $a>0$.

I know that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{a}\coth \pi a$ with $a>0$ but I cannot combine that to get the other series, since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}\ne2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac1{a^2}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}$$